# How to perform data comparison between 2 kafka topic using flink

Tags: java, apache-kafka, comparison, apache-flink

I got stuck at scenario where i need to consume data stream from 2 or more kafka topics(after applying filter) and compare the data. Since the data volume is high, Please suggest the best options available..
Is it possible with flink?

Comment: what kind of comparison do you need to do?

Comment: Yes, this should be possible with Flink. But to suggest a solution we'll need to know more about the kind of comparison involved.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I would like to perform field/attribute level comparison or minus operation between data from 2 kafka topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways one might potentially use to approach this with Flink. The more straightforward options are probably to either use

- [an interval join](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/joining.html#interval-join)
- or some sort of [Table](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/tableApi.html#joins) or [SQL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql.html#joins) join.

Using Kafka with the Table/SQL APi is covered [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connect.html#kafka-connector).

Comment: Is the join options suggested here capable of minus operation ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by minus, but the Table/SQL API supports subtraction on numeric values, and EXCEPT on sets. And you can always extend the built-in operations with user-defined functions. With the interval join you can do anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try Spark streaming? Spark has connectors to read from Kafka topics and view them as a table (aka., dataframe) and you can run SQL queries on top of the dataframe and compare results.